# Content-length does not appear with nginx and php files

Tags: nginx, web-server, http-headers

I have a nginx server which serve a website. 
With my browser i can reach index.php, but when i look at the headers with firebug, i can't see the content-length on any php files, but for example i can see it on html files.

With a apache server, i can see this content-length on every type of file.

I use a loadbalancer that's why i need this parameter to be sent!

Have you ever had this kind of problem with nginx ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is chunked encoding (you'll see a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header), and understanding this encoding in place of `Content-Length` is a requirement for any HTTP/1.1-compliant application.

From the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt): `All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the "chunked" transfer-coding`.

nginx is behaving properly; if your load balancer can't handle it, but still acts like an HTTP/1.1 system, then it's the one to blame.  What kind of load balancer is it?

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, My LB is the ec2 one. And i think that it is not able to decode the "chunked"...